# Couchbase: Is it possible to create "joined" view through couch?

Tags: view, key, parent-child, couchbase

I'm currently developing website which uses Couchbase as DB manager.
In my data I have objects which have parent-children relationship. for logical reasons this is more convenience (and logically correct) in my app that the parent will know all its children (by containing array of IDs) and not the opposite as usual in couch.
**Is it possible to make one view that return, by query with the the parent id, all the children of the object?**
view-collision isn't possible because the children doesn't have parent_id. so Is there a way inside map function of view to use another view? or reference the own view? or maybe a sophisticated reduce function can help, or 2 phases view which first obtain the children ids and then query the view, something like couchbase inner function if possible.

Comment: If you have the parent key and that parent object has the child ids, why can't you do a multi get on those ids?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest Views, nor can you reference other Views for many reasons. However you can collate documents together and simulate a join by using information in the documents and processing them via a single map function. In our docs you can read about it here: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#solutions-for-simulating-joins

Let me know and I can give further instructions on how to do so if you need it.

Also it's not uncommon at all to have a bi-directional references in your documents. So you can put the parent id in the child documents. Of course then you also have to update them if that relationship changes. In addition, you can have siblings as well, with the added application feature of changing sibling lists amongst all siblings if that information changes. Like humans, child documents can have multiple parents too of course, and you can have references to both.

Of course, like @scalabilitysolved said, if you know the parent, you can just multi-get on the array of children and not even need a View at all unless you have to search for the parent via various JSON properties and not the key itself.

Answer (score -1):

The requested feature, as described in your question, is not possible in Couchbase 2.2.  As I recently posted on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076688/how-does-simulating-joins-works-in-couchbase), you will need to perform multiple view queries to build your result set (this is no big deal as queries are very fast in couchbase).

Also, I should point out that views are not supposed to contain your whole object (it would completely defeat the purpose of a view). So, it would stand to reason that your architecture doesn't need a view at all - you query CB for your parent object, and the parent contains all of the document id's for the child objects. If you need the child objects, you need to query for them.

As an aside, I'm glad that CB doesn't support what you are requesting, because it could really lead to misuse of the platform by overthinking the design. Gotta take off your SQL server hat - multiple queries in CB are optimal and preferred.